# How to delay instantiation of Prefabs inside a TileMap

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making Super Mario Bros in Unity. I am using TileMap populated with prefabs (for enemies and interactive tiles)

The problem is, these gets instantiated as soon as the game start, this is bad because of:

- performance
- the enemies start walking around and fall out of the map even before the player gets to them.

How is this usually handled?
A script that checks the distance from each item to the player an calls SetActive(true)?

Comment: `A script that checks the distance from each item to the player an calls SetActive(true)?` for example, yes why not? Could even group them into sections and have a single check to activate a batch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, usually a really large Unity game is handled with Sub-Scenes, where you enable/disable portions of the level based on if the player is near or not.

[Here you can see an example of additive scenes saving performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6-0zD9Xyu5c) (I don't think you need them unless you have a 1Km map).

Before thinking about Sub-Scenes you should remember that every Super Mario Bros enemy is simulated when you get close, but he would never jump down the map even if active for hours, you have to make the enemy AI smart enought to avoid jumping in the void.

For example, a movement not using rigidbody:

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {
   //This is the layer mask of the terrain, we want not to jump into the void
   public LayerMask groundLayerMask; 
   //Move speed of the enemy (mess with it, if the enemy does not move, increase this)
   public float moveSpeed;

   //If the terrain distance is greater, then we change direction
   private static readonly float MaxTerrainDistance = .1f;

   private bool leftDirection;

   private void FixedUpdate(){
      Vector2 direction = leftDirection ? -transform.right : transform.right;
      Vector2 nextEnemyStep = direction * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

      //We check if we have the ground under our next step 2 (we skip a cicle)
      if (!Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position + nextEnemyStep * 2, -transform.up, MaxTerrainDistance, groundLayerMask))
         leftDirection = !leftDirection;

      transform.Translate(nextEnemyStep);
   }
}
```